# Most pythonic way to initialize a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have a dict like this

```
d = {
    1: [1,4,7],
    2: [2,5,8],
    0: [3,6,9]       
}
```

It can be constructed by

```
d = {}

for i in range(1,10):
    key = i % 3
    if key not in d: d[key] = []
    d[key].append(i)
```

I used this line `if key not in d: d[key] = []` to check existence of the key/value pair in the dict and initiate the pair.

Is there a more pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: why you can't use array ?

Comment: [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably best handled with a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), which will automatically create any key-value mapping that is accessed if it doesn't already exist. You pass a callable to the `defaultdict` constructor that will be used to initialize the value. For example:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d
defaultdict(list, {})
>>> d[3]
[]
>>> d
defaultdict(list, {3: []})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a comprehension:

```
>>> {n%3: list(range(n, n+7, 3)) for n in range(1,4)}
{0: [3, 6, 9], 1: [1, 4, 7], 2: [2, 5, 8]}
```

Using `dict.setdefault()`:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for i in range(1, 10):
...     d.setdefault(i%3, []).append(i)
... 
>>> d
{0: [3, 6, 9], 1: [1, 4, 7], 2: [2, 5, 8]}
```

Using `defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i in range(1, 10):
...     d[i%3].append(i)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [3, 6, 9], 1: [1, 4, 7], 2: [2, 5, 8]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list slices [start:stop:step] nominclature

```
d={}
for i in range(3):
     d[i] = list(range(1,10))[(i+2)%3::3]

{0: [3, 6, 9],
 1: [1, 4, 7], 
 2: [2, 5, 8]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(1,10):
    key = i % 3
    d[key].append(i)
print(d)
```

out:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [3, 6, 9], 1: [1, 4, 7], 2: [2, 5, 8]})
```

> When each key is encountered for the first time, it is not already in
>   the mapping; so an entry is automatically created using the
>   default_factory function which returns an empty list. The
>   list.append() operation then attaches the value to the new list. When
>   keys are encountered again, the look-up proceeds normally (returning
>   the list for that key) and the list.append() operation adds another
>   value to the list. This technique is simpler and faster than an
>   equivalent technique using dict.setdefault():

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for k, v in s:  
        d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you haven't given any input nor variable parts you might just initialize it with the literal you already have:

```
d = {1: [1,4,7],
     2: [2,5,8],
     0: [3,6,9]}
```

---

If you have variable input you may use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with `list` as factory. Given that this operation is very common several external libraries have functions for this:

- [`iteration_utilities.groupedby`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/groupedby.html)
- [`toolz.groupby`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.groupby)

For example:

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import groupedby

>>> groupedby(range(1, 10), lambda x: x % 3)
{0: [3, 6, 9], 1: [1, 4, 7], 2: [2, 5, 8]}
```

or:

```
>>> from toolz import groupby

>>> groupby(lambda x: x % 3, range(1, 10))
{0: [3, 6, 9], 1: [1, 4, 7], 2: [2, 5, 8]}
```